# Big-O runtimes in loops

Tags: java, big-o

Well, i am trying to figure out the Big O runtimes in this loop. I have the answers but i would like to check with the community.

```
 m =1;                                            1                                                       
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)                        n+1                               
 for (j = 1; j <= n*n; j++)                     n(n+1) =  n^2+n                       
 for (k = 1; k <= n*n*n; k++)                  n(n^2+n) = n^3+n^2
 M++;                                          1*n*n*n
```

My answer for complexity is O(n^3)

1. How many does the instruction m++ apply?

   My answer was n^3*n^2*n but i am not sure
2. What is the value for m when the process has finished?

   My answer was 1*n *n *n

Is this correct?

Comment: Are those nested loops? Then, no, the complexity is a few degrees higher.

Comment: If the loops are nested, the complexity is `O(n^6)`.

Comment: Hint: if you say `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) { ... }}`, the body of the loop is executed 4*5=20 times, right?  So you'll need to do some multiplication.

Comment: How do you get from (1) `n^3 * n^2 * n` to (2) `1*n*n*n` ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is somewhat simplified in that the three loops have no functional dependence on each other (other than that they are nested together), so we can just multilply the complexities of each loop together to get a final answer.

The `k` loop is `O(n^3)`, because the upper bound of the loop is `n*n*n`.  By similar reasoning, the middle loop is `O(n^2)` and the outer loop is `O(n)`.  Multiplying together we get `O(n^6)`.

I think the "trap" of this question would be duping someone into thinking that because the loop with the highest complexity is `O(n^3)` that therefore this term dominates the expression, which then must also be overall `O(n^3)`.  This isn't the case as hopefully you can see by now.